# How can I look at Airport logs?

Tags: airport

I have a VirginMedia connection using one of their "Super Hub"'s, their wireless configuration is turned off and I connect my Airport Extreme via RJ45 cable.
I connect my iMac from the Extreme via RJ45, and it is configured for wireless also.
Connected to the Airport Extreme extending my wireless network is an Airport Express.
My internet connection is over 60 meg and that's all ok, but the other devices using the Airport and the Extreme run very slow , so much so that it is impossible to watch streamed TV to any device.

I would like to look at any logs that the devices create to see if I can see a problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Console

Type Airport in Search (for all messages)

Or Scroll all the way down to wifi

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities which can log the details of what is happening on an Airport Extreme, they all use SNMP (which means Simple network Management Protocol).

You need to enable SNMP on your AE, and then use a tool like Netuse app to monitor what is happening. http://www.netuseapp.com

Have you done tests to compare the speed difference between wifi to the AE, ethernet to the AE and ethernet to the super hub? I'd be curious to see where the bottleneck actually is.

The other thing I would check is your network setup, and make sure you're not providing DHCP on the super hub and the AE, which would do what's called "double NAT" and affect your network. If you have DHCP on both devices then you need to turn it off on the AE and let the super hub handle it. If you do not want that, then set the  super hub to bridge mode and then let the AE do all the networking.

HTH,

Dave

Comment: Found that if I reset the Airport Express with reset button and it then loaded it's config automatically from the utility, it now works a 6meg which is 10% of my Airport Extreme. I was wondering why it's only 10% of my total and can it be configured higher?  And yes I have turned off the Virgin SuperHub's wifi.

Comment: How do I enable snmp on my AE? I have looked at the AE screens but cant see it?

Comment: Once again the Netuse app folks come in handy: http://www.netuseapp.com/faq-netuse-traffic-monitor  See the question "Q: I have upgraded my Airport Configuration Utility to version 6.0 and I don’t see SNMP configuration options anywhere. How do I enable SNMP on my Airport Extreme or Time Capsule?" You will need to install the  version 5 of the AE software and use that to enable SNMP.